# cameracalibrator.py GUI opens but is not drawn

Tags: calibration, ros-kinetic, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to calibrate a single camera using cameracalibrator, as explained in http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration
Despite being able to see the camera using `rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image_raw`, I cannot start cameracalibrator.
After issuing `rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 9x6 --square 0.05   images:=/camera/image_raw camera:=/camera`, I get the following output:

```
('Waiting for service', '/camera/set_camera_info', '...')
OK
init done
```

The window appears, but contents are not draw. There's no video feed nor slider controls when I use that command. How do I solve that? This is using Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04

If it helps:

```
$ rostopic list
/camera/camera_info
/camera/image_raw
/camera/image_raw/compressed
/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/image_raw/theora
/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/mycam/parameter_descriptions
/camera/mycam/parameter_updates
/rosout
/rosout_agg
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256679/cameracalibrator.py-gui-opens-but-is-not-drawn/) by [Vitor](https://answers.ros.org/users/29650/vitor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-03-10

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davelkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23120/davelkan/) on 2017-10-12**:
I'm having the exact same issue after installing 16,04 fresh. Did you ever resolve this issue? Would be very interested to hear if you did.

**Comment by [fulkast@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/37270/fulkast@gmail.com/) on 2018-08-31**:
Have you tried running it with the "--no-service-check" option? Meaning running "rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 9x6 --square 0.05 images:=/camera/image_raw camera:=/camera **--no-service-check**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think i see the problem here. Through my own trials i observed that the symptoms you are describing occur when the image has not yet been received by the calibration gui node. It doesn't draw any images until it's received an image.

It looks like you're remapping the incorrect topic, which would explain why the image has not been received.
`rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 9x6 --square 0.05 images:=/camera/image_raw camera:=/camera` is remapping "images" and should be remapping "image".  You can check this by comparing the subscribed topics under `rosnode info /camreacalibrator` to the topics viewable by `rostopic list`

---

Originally posted by [davelkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23120/davelkan/) with karma: 71 on 2017-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1